# What does "snake the cab line" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The whole sentence is `The taxi-on-demand service Uber lets you snake the cab line.`.

And why is snake used here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *snake* here serves as a *verb* and not *noun*. It means that using the service of Uber, you can have a taxi-on-demand and get rid of standing in a cab line by **moving** through it.

More about the verb *snake* [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snake).

Comment: Thanks Maulik, I must say at first I can't help but thinking that using `snake` as a verb kind of implied that one moved very slowly, (share some similarity with `crawl`)? .. But then I remembered how smooth the snake looks like and how smoothly it moves, and I think I've got the idea of using it in that `snake the cab line` context. @Maulik V

Comment: @Evelyn1986 You are welcome! We all are here to help each others!